# Сортировка всех массивов по примеру одного массива NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone

Добрых времени суток.

Имеется массив с числами, допустим, это числа рейтинга - 5, 1, 2, 6, 8, я могу отсортировать его через:

> ```
> students2b = [students2 sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
>         return [[numFormatter numberFromString:a] compare:[numFormatter numberFromString:b]];
> }];
> ```

Тут особо ума не надо, массив students2b станет по порядку - 1, 2, 5, 6, 8.

Но также имеются еще 2 массива, допустим, это Имя и Фамилия.

Как мне их поставить на места, по которым был расставлен массив с числами?

Чтоб в итоге получилось из:

```
5     Олег           Романов
2     Никита         Смирнов
7     Анна           Лучик
4     Владимир       Лисицын
```

в это

```
2     Никита         Смирнов
4     Владимир       Лисицын
5     Олег           Романов
7     Анна           Лучик
```

Эти массивы берутся с Базы Данных - в JSON, выводить с сервера сразу отсортированными не могу, т.к. рейтинг подсчитывается и запихивается в массив при получении уже клиентом, дабы не нагружать сервер.

После сортировки отправлю в TableView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@An0nimchic](/users/23245/an0nimchic)](/users/23245/an0nimchic), вот с примером:

Создать класс

```
@interface Student: NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *lastName;
@property (nonatomic) float rating;

@end
```

дальше заполняем массив объектами студент:

```
Student *student = [Student new];
student.firstName = @"Иван";
student.lastName = @"Семенов";
student.rating = 2.2;
```

если у вас оригинально все в трех массивах с соответствием по индексам, то:

```
__block NSMutableArray *originalStudents = [NSMutableArray array];
[firstNamesArray enumarateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *name, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    Student *student = [Student new];
    student.firstName = name;
    student.lastName = lastNamesArray[idx];
    student.rating = [students2[idx] floatValue];
    [originalStudents addObject:student];
}];
```

ну и сортировка:

```
NSArray *sortedStudents = [originalStudents sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"rating" ascending: true], [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"lastName" ascending: true]];
```

Можно сортировать по скольким ключам сразу в приоритете их индекса в массиве NSSortDescriptors.

Comment: Благодарю за пример, не первый раз меня спасаете. <3

Comment: @iFreeman, а как теперь доставать объекты с массива? [sortedStudents objectAtIndex:1] - выдаст объект в виде <Student: 0x79a79020>.

Comment: @An0nimchic: Хм, дайте подумать. Как же достать свойства из объекта?

Comment: objectForKey и objectAtIndex только использовал

Comment: @An0nimchic

    Student *student = students[index]; NSString *name = student.firstName;

Comment: @VladD, @An0nimchic, еще можно через [[students valueForKeyPath:@"name"] objectAtIndex:1]. Совсем подзабыл. Благодарю за ответы.

Answer (score 2):

А зачем вам вообще 3 массива? Заведите класс с описанием свойств студента и сравнивайте в `sortedArrayUsingComparator` не просто a и b, а `a.rate` и `b.rate`

**Обновление**

Какой микропример-то? Создаете класс student со свойствами rate, name, surname, при парсинге json соотвественно пишете данные не в 3 массива, а сначала создаете объект класса student, в него забиваете все данные, а уже этот объект добавляете в один-единственный массив. Ну а потом его сортируете тем же способом что у вас уже есть, только вместо `[[numFormatter numberFromString:a] compare:[numFormatter numberFromString:b]];` пишете `[a.rate compare:b.rate];`, а преобразование `numberFromString` можете сделать на этапе парсинга, хотя оно по-моему и не нужно - у строк тоже есть метод `compare`

Comment: aknew, очень интересный вариант, но можно поподробнее, микро-пример если Вам не сложно, дальше я уже подхвачу.

Answer (score 1):

[[@An0nimchic](/users/23245/an0nimchic)](/users/23245/an0nimchic): Заводите структуру данных `Student` с полями/свойствами `int rating`, `NSString* firstName`, `NSString* lastName`, и сортируете по нужному полю.

Заодно вам не придётся парсить строку в число при каждом сравнении.